# While loop causes my JavaFX application to crash

Tags: javafx

I am trying to check my ArrayLists (which are stored in the class GrocerieList) and add them to my TreeView Branches. I can display single ones without going over the while loop. Since they are dynamic however i need some kind of loop. Currently the ArrayList foodAmount ("4" )and foodList ("pizza") both hold one item each.

Here is my code with the while loop (I excluded the other branches for readability):

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    TextField nameInput, quantityInput;
    TreeView<String> tree;

    GrocerieList shoppingList = new GrocerieList();
    Storage storage = new Storage();
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String item;
    static String quant;
    static String exit = "exit";
    static int menuchoice;
    static int catchoice;
    static int marketchoice;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        loadFile();
        launch(args);

    }

    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("GrocerieList");

        // tree view
        TreeItem<String> root, food, drink, hygiene, other;

        root = new TreeItem<>();
        root.setExpanded(true);

        // food
        food = makeBranch("Food",root);
        while(GrocerieList.foodList.listIterator().hasNext()) {
            makeBranch("[" + GrocerieList.foodAmount.listIterator().next() + "] " + GrocerieList.foodList.listIterator().next(), food);
        }

        // tree
    tree = new TreeView<>(root);
    tree.setShowRoot(false);
    tree.getStyleClass().add("myTree");

    // bottom input fields
    nameInput = new TextField();
    nameInput.setPromptText("Productname");
    nameInput.setMinWidth(100);

    quantityInput = new TextField();
    quantityInput.setPromptText("Quantity");
    quantityInput.setMinWidth(100);

    // buttons
    Button addbutton = new Button("Add");

    // Layout
    // HBOX
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    hBox.setSpacing(30);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, quantityInput, addbutton);

    // BorderPane
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(tree);
    borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
    borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(20));

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 520, 620);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("Viper.css");
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
```

This is the class that contains my ArrayLists:

```
public class GrocerieList {

    static ArrayList<String> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> hygieneList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> drinkList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> otherList = new ArrayList<>();

    static ArrayList<String> foodAmount = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> hygieneAmount = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> drinkAmount = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> otherAmount = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: you are not checking in the while loop if "foodAmount.listIterator().hasNext()",
it might be possible that foodAmount elements are less than foodList?

Comment: Well the application doesnt start and java crashes. ActivityMonitor shows that Java uses upwards of 500 percent cpu power and doesnt respond - whenever i take the while loop out it works just fine.

Comment: They always have the same amount - that is defined at the point they are input

Comment: `listIterator()` returns a new iterator, positioned at the beginning of the list. So your `while` condition will always be true. The way you have this structured, you need to keep references to both iterators and ensure you call `hasNext()` on the same iterator each time, and also ensure you call `next()` on both iterators each time. This just isn't the way to do this, though; you should use an object-oriented approach and define a class whose instances contain the data you need in a single iteration. Then keep a single list of those objects and iterate over it in the normal way.